# Drupal 7 test login throws exception Undefined property: MyTest::$public_files_directory

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to do some tests in my drupal's 7 module. So i followed drupal's SimpleTest Api and i implemented some tests

For example i'm testing the login process.

```
   public function  testLogin() {
    $user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array());
    $this->drupalLogin($user);
   }
```

When i'm trying to login, i'm getting always this exception:

```
Undefined property: MyModuleTest::$public_files_directory drupal_web_test_case.php  1692 DrupalWebTestCase->curlInitialize()
```

After that exception login fails.

The verbose message was this:

```
User created with name zPUkpgzN and pass 6NXRDGWy5k Pass
GET http://www.example.com/user returned 200 (1 byte). Pass
Valid HTML found on "http://www.example.com/user" Pass
Failed to set field name to zPUkpgzN Pass
Failed to set field pass to 6NXRDGWy5k Fail
Found the Log in button Fail
Found the requested form fields at user Fail
User zPUkpgzN successfully logged in.   Fail
```

I found this post http://drupal.org/node/1789942, and I followed some suggestions but the only thing i succeeded was this:

```
User created with name zPUkpgzN and pass 6NXRDGWy5k Pass
GET http://www.example.com/user returned 200 (1 byte). Pass
Valid HTML found on "http://www.example.com/user" Pass
Failed to set field name to zPUkpgzN Pass
Failed to set field pass to 6NXRDGWy5k Pass
Found the Log in button Fail
Found the requested form fields at user Pass
User zPUkpgzN successfully logged in.   Fail
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Thandem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it a minute ago. The Exception remains but the test has succeeded.

```
I followed this approach:

  public function  testLogin() {
    $user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array());
    $user->roles[] = 'authenticated user'; //Defining user role
    user_save( $user ); //Save user in testing database

    $this->drupalLogin($user);//success!!!!
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call parent::setUp(), $public_files_directory does not get defined.

Comment: Taking a cue from `DrupalWebTestCase::setUp()`, I added the following to my setUp(): `$this->public_files_directory = variable_get('file_public_path');`